# batch script to kill last application

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, autohotkey, taskkill

I would like to create a batch script, which when launched by a keyboard shortcut, will use `taskkill /f /im` to force quit the last application I was on.

I think that this could probably work by getting the last app's name as a variable, and then killing it (that variable), but I'm unfamiliar with batch, and don't know how applications/processes work in Windows. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried using the following script, which I got from [here](https://baksteenbrick.wordpress.com/2011/06/30/force-quit-autohotkey-script/), but unfortunately that didn't work.

```
Pause::
WinGet,win_pid,PID,A
Run,taskkill /f /pid %win_pid%,,,
return
```

Comment: Of course this doesn't work, because this is not a batch file but an AutoHotkey script...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using AutoHotKey

You need to install autoHotKey in order to use this script.

You can download it @ https://www.autohotkey.com/

After you download and install it, have a look at the [documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Program.htm#run).

I think you should go through the first 3 sections since it will be beneficial for you to understand:

- how scripts work
- how to edit them
- how to run them

It's really a 5 minute read.